# Refactor this function to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 17 to the 15 allowed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, sonarqube

I'm getting this error on Sonarqube for if case, please help me to resolve this

```
if (cameFrom === 'textbox') {
    let exceedMinPrice = false;
    let exceedMaxPrice = false;
    let priceRangeError = false;
    if (low < minValue) {
      exceedMinPrice = true;
    }
    if (high > maxValue) {
      exceedMaxPrice = true;
    }
    if (high < low) {
      priceRangeError = true;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: perhaps ... `let exceedMinPrice = low < minValue;` etc ?

Comment: @JaromandaX was about to say the same, those are easy wins.

Comment: @JaromandaX, Got it now. Thank you

Comment: No probs - eventually you'll figure out how to embed an image too :p

Comment: Please use the preview before you post a question and check if everything is "visible" and looks as it should look like

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what the tool your using is trying to indicate exactly, but one possible solution reduce cognitive complexity is as follows:

```js
const exceedMinPrice = (low < minValue);
const exceedMaxPrice = (high > maxValue);
const priceRangeError = (high < low);
```

Comment: Yes @richard, This is fixed now. Thank you